# xamarin Syncfusion carousel with dots

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel, syncfusion

I have a implement syncfusion Carousel and binding items using ItemTemplate.When i load the items to Carousel all item appears in Carousel view.But i need to add a doted indicator for it.
When user swipe though the Carousel  by the dots should indicate current position.
When reading from documentation of syncfusion rotator have this functionality.
I need to add this to carousel view.

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried to fulfil your need? I am voting to close your question because it appears to me it is low quality.

Comment: he has not actually asked a question

Comment: I believe i have ask the question i wanted to add dots to carousal view.
"But i need to add a doted indicator for it"

Comment: @Black If you like to try another plugin, Give a try to this carousal view. This have all the properties you mentioned. https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find all the [SfCarousel Class Members](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/xamarin/Syncfusion.SfCarousel.XForms%7ESyncfusion.SfCarousel.XForms.SfCarousel_members.html).

And there's no property for the dots you refered in the SfCarousel print.

In fact, I think you are confusing it with another component called [SfRotator](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/rotator/overview). (that has an identical example like your print). and the property you are looking for is called: **DotPlacement**.

And can have the following states:

- None `//No Dots`
- Default `//Dots Inside the Rotator View`
- OutSide `//Dots Outside the Rotator View`

Comment: Is it possible to combine those two.that means im using carousal view to show content and use only sfrotator DotPlacement to show the dots?
but both should work together

Comment: @Black well.. you can overlap them and make the Source and SelectedIndex the same, and with a grid make the Carousel above the Rotator, but thats a really bad idea, my advise is to create a functionality that creates Dots based on the number of elements of your DataSource, and change the dot color based on the SelectedIndex

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed your query and currently we don’t have dots view support in CarouselView. However, we can fulfill this requirement by using Border or Button control as like below code snippet.

Custom DotsView:

XAML:

```
    <border:SfBorder BorderColor="{Binding ThumbBorder}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" BorderWidth="5" CornerRadius="50"  />
```

Carousel View:

XAML:

```
<carousel:SfCarousel x:Name="carousel"  Grid.Row="0" Offset="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageCollection}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}" 
                       ItemHeight="200" SelectionChanged="Carousel_SelectionChanged"
                                       ItemWidth="200" />
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="rotatorThumb" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
```

C#:

```
  public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Command command = new Command((object thumb) =>
        {
            var thumbView = thumb as DotsView;
            if (thumbView != null)
            {
                ((rotatorThumb.Children[carousel.SelectedIndex] as DotsView).BindingContext as CarouselModel).
                    ThumbBorder = Color.LightGray;
                carousel.SelectedIndex = thumbView.Index;
                (thumbView.BindingContext as CarouselModel).ThumbBorder = Color.Red;
            }
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < ImageCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            var itemView = new DotsView() { BindingContext = ImageCollection[i], Index = i };
            if (carousel.SelectedIndex == i)
                (itemView.BindingContext as CarouselModel).ThumbBorder = Color.Red;
            TapGestureRecognizer thumbTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            thumbTap.Command = command;
            itemView.GestureRecognizers.Add(thumbTap);
            thumbTap.CommandParameter = itemView;
            rotatorThumb.Children.Add(itemView);
        }

   }
```

Output:
[image]

[Sample](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/CarouselSample-910260730.zip)